# ORA-14300: partitioning key maps to a partition outside maximum permitted number of partitions

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning

I have created below table with partitioning :

```
CREATE TABLE FRD_TBL_H (DAT NUMBER(8), DATST NUMBER(8), MEST VARCHAR2(1 CHAR), MEST1 VARCHAR2(1 CHAR), BELD CHAR(11 CHAR),VALID_FROM DATE, VALID_TO DATE) 
PARTITION BY RANGE(valid_to)
    INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH')) 
        ( PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-01-1999', 'DD-MM-YYYY')))
         ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;
```

I am trying to insert data into this table by keeping valid_to value to null and also i tried valid_to value to '01-01-1999' but getting below error:

```
ORA-14300: partitioning key maps to a partition outside maximum permitted number of partitions
```

I did partioning by month on valid_to column because the table has 70 million rows and i am writing below mere query for historization logic:

```
MERGE INTO FRD_TBL_H e 
    USING FRD_TBL h 
    ON (e.beld = h.beld) 
  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET e.valid_from = sysdate 
where e.valid_to = 01.01.1999
```

Comment: Can you show us your insert statements ?

Comment: With your DDL and `insert into FRD_TBL_H (VALID_TO) values ('01-JAN-1999')`, I see no error in RDBMS 19.9.0.0.0. Either your use case is different than what you posted or you've uncovered a bug that I'm not seeing. A null value *must* produce the error you show because null cannot identify a partition.

Comment: @JeffHolt null value throws the error I believe

Comment: @VBoka Yes, by definition it *must* but the OP makes it seem like the not null value given also produces the error.

Comment: @JeffHolt I agree.

Comment: i was trying with insert using select query but i miss this valid_to column in the query..i will test again

Comment: *Please* include your actual insert and merge statements, and any errors you get from each one. Setting `valid_to` to null will error, as already mentioned; using 1999-01-01 will not. The merge isn't valid - `01.01.1999` is neither a date nor a string that can be implicitly converted to a date. With a real date [what you have shown works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=513dc672e9fae224890950fa56836bd6). It isn't clear from your question what you are doing and seeing, so please update to clarify the problem.

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks its working now the problem was i was using insert using select and i forgot to add valid_to column...one question...do you think it makes sense as i have created parition month on valid_to for performance optimization of my Merge query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum number of partitions in Oracle is [1024K - 1](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/refrn/logical-database-limits.html#GUID-685230CF-63F5-4C5A-B8B0-037C566BDA76)  = 1048575

What are you probably doing is the following. You created the table with **day** partitioning. (Not month as you posted).

```
CREATE TABLE FRD_TBL_H (DAT NUMBER(8), DATST NUMBER(8), MEST VARCHAR2(1 CHAR), MEST1 VARCHAR2(1 CHAR), BELD CHAR(11 CHAR),VALID_FROM DATE, VALID_TO DATE) 
PARTITION BY RANGE(valid_to)
    INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(1, 'DAY')) 
        ( PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-01-1999', 'DD-MM-YYYY')))
         ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;
```

And used a *sufficiently high* `valid_to` date e.g. `DATE'4999-01-01'`

```
insert into FRD_TBL_H( VALID_TO) values (DATE'4999-01-01');  
ORA-14300: partitioning key maps to a partition outside maximum permitted number of partitions
```

A simple calculation shows, that the partition limit is indeed broken

```
select 1024*1024-1 max_part, DATE'4999-01-01' - TO_DATE('01-01-1999', 'DD-MM-YYYY') day_diff from dual;

 MAX_PART   DAY_DIFF
---------- ----------
   1048575    1095728
```

So this is expected bahavior.

The real question is, why do you use `valid_to` as the *partition key* and not `valid_from`.

With `valid_from` you will

- have not the problem with the `null` or *dummy* value
- the column will not change, so no need for *row movement*
- most queries use the predicate `:1 >= valid_from` so the *pruning* will work fine

To get an efficient acces to the *open* (last) version you may use *composite partitioning* with `validfrom` date *range partitioning* and *list subpartitioning* for open / closed versions.

Comment: actually i am paritioning by Month and update my question and added point why i use valid_to as the partition key

Comment: Than post the `insert` raising the exception @Andrew. Oracle covers approx. 15K year in the `DATE` data type, corresponding to about 180K *months* - this is below the partition count limit...

Comment: thanks its working now the problem was i was using insert using select and i forgot to add valid_to column...one question...do you think it makes sense as i have created parition month on valid_to for performance optimization of my Merge query ?

Comment: Please post it in extra question. For sure a `MERGE` will profit if you update only one partition. But don't forget, your target is also to have effective *queries* on the table - this could be even more important than the maintainance of the table. @Andrew