# enabling ROW_MOVEMENT in Oracle 19?

Tags: oracle, merge, partitioning, oracle19c

I have table `TRD_TEST2` in which I have created below partition for performance improvement as the table has 80 million records:

```
PARTITION BY RANGE(valid_to)
    INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH')) 
        ( PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-01-3999', 'DD-MM-YYYY')))
         ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;
```

For history purposes, we have created technical key columns `valid_from` and `valid_to` in `TRD_TEST2` table. Below is the `Merge` query which we are running daily:

```
MERGE INTO TRD_TEST2 e
    USING TRD_TEST2_SRC h
    ON (e.ld= h.ld)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET e.valid_to = sysdate,
    IS_CURRENT = 0
where e.valid_to = TO_DATE('01.01.3999', 'DD.MM.YYYY');
```

I would like to know does it make sense to enable `ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT` in this case as we are updating `valid_to` column using the above `Merge` query daily and what is the impact?

Comment: `PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (DATE '3999-01-01')` means you create one partition and then **all** data goes into this partition - unless you split the partition afterwards or you insert data **after** 3999-01-01 which seem to be very unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that the question makes sense.

If you are partitioning on `valid_to` and updating `valid_to` then you must enable row movement.  If you don't enable row movement, as soon as you try to update a row in a way that would force it into a different partition, you'll get an error.

Choosing a partition key that is expected to change is generally frowned upon.  Moving a row effectively turns an `update` into a `delete` and `insert` which will be significantly more expensive (how much will depend on how much of the cost is redo generation and how much redo is generated by the two operations).  As was suggested in [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71603033/ora-14300-partitioning-key-maps-to-a-partition-outside-maximum-permitted-number), partitioning on `valid_from` would seem to make more sense in general since it is a static, `NOT NULL` column.  And that saves you from having to assign fake `valid_to` values to current rows.  If your only concern is the performance of this `merge` statement rather than all the other queries against this table, though, partitioning on `valid_to` might make sense for you.

Comment: thanks understood now ..so i wll need ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT as i will update daily valid_to column